# Как использовать foreach в javascript для xml массива?

Tags: javascript

```
        var xml = <note>
               <to>Tove</to>
               <from>Jani</from>
               <heading>Reminder</heading>
               <body><link>link</link><entry>test</entry><entry>test1</entry><entry>test2</entry></body>  
           </note>  
    xml.foreach(function(test){
    document.write(test); // так делать вывод  ?
<a href="link"><entry></a>
    });
```

Что бы test test1 test2 выводились и генерились и `<a href="link"><entry></a>` так выводились?

Comment: А где массив то у тебя?

Comment: вообще я про xml файл вывод данных из него по foreach! Я не знаю как это сделать( по json все более понятно

Comment: Ну во-первых  не `foreach`,  а `forEach`

Comment: А во-вторых чтобы `xml` стал массивом сделай его массивом ну или хотя бы строкой

Comment: И в-третьих,  вообще не понятно, что ты хочешь реализовать.

Comment: Хочу записи вывести как новости из xml -ки я не знаю как поэтому такой вопрос неопределенный

Comment: А они у тебя в отдельном файле `xml`?

Comment: xml получаю с веб сервиса тут просто аналог сделал

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если так уж хочется поюзать `forEach`, то ваш парсер будет примерно таким:

```js
var xml = `
  <note>
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>
  <link>link</link>
  <entry>test</entry>
  <entry>test1</entry>
  <entry>test2</entry>
  </body>
  </note>
  `;
var sLink = xml.replace(/[\s\S]*<link>(.*?)<\/link>[\s\S]*/g, '$1');
xml.match(/<entry>(.*?)<\/entry>/g).forEach(function(entry) {
  document.write(`<a href="${sLink}">${entry}</a><br>`);
});
```

Comment: ну да, xml Не html можно и регуляркой :)

Comment: @Grundy дык, это первое, что в голову приходит, исходя из информативности вопроса :)